# 3-dimensional integral with many absolute values and parameters

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate the expectation value of $L_{z}=-ih \left(x\frac{d}{dy}-y\frac{d}{dx} \right)$  for the state : $$\phi(x,y,z) = a^{5/2} e^{-a(|x|+|y|+|z|) } (x+iy),$$ where $a>0$. So, I need to calculate the integral: 
>   $$ \langle L_{z} \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{\phi}L_{z} \phi \hspace{1mm}
> dx \hspace{1mm} dy \hspace{1mm} dz  = \int a^{5/2}e^{-a(|x|+|y|+|z|)}(x\frac{d}{dy}-y\frac{d}{dx})a^{5/2}e^{-a(|x|+|y|+|z|)}(x+iy) \hspace{1mm} dx \hspace{1mm}dy \hspace{1mm} dz .$$

The possible cases are:

1. $x>0, y>0, z>0$;
2. $x<0, y<0, z<0$;
3. $x>0, y<0, z<0$;
4. $x>0, y>0, z<0$;
5. $x<0, y>0, z<0$;
6. $x<0, y<0, z>0$;
7. $x>0, y<0, z>0$

which gives the six integrals:

1. $\displaystyle \int a^{5} e^{-2a(x+y+z)}(x^{2}+y^{2}\;dx\;dy\;dz$
2. $\displaystyle \int a^5 e^{-2a(-x-y-z)} (x^2+y^2)\;dx\;dy\;dz$
3. $\displaystyle \int a^5 e^{-2a(x-y-z)} (x^2+y^2)\;dx\;dy\;dz$
4. $\displaystyle \int a^5 e^{-2a(x+y-z)} (x^2+y^2)\;dx\;dy\;dz$
5. $\displaystyle \int a^5 e^{-2a(-x+y-z)} (x^2+y^2)\;dx\;dy\;dz$
6. $\displaystyle \int a^5 e^{-2a(-x-y+z)} (x^2+y^2)\;dx\;dy\;dz$
7. $\displaystyle \int a^5 e^{-2a(x-y+z)} (x^2+y^2)\;dx\;dy\;dz$

   Does anybody see how to reduce this to a integral of one variable? Please do tell.

Edit: there is a horrible mistake, I forgot to multiply within the integral by $L_{z}$, Srivatsans solutions for the "wrong" integral stays true, though.

I come to:

$\displaystyle{ \int \int \int (x-iy)a^{5/2}e^{-a(|x|+|y|+|z|)}(-i\hbar(x\frac{d}{dy}-y\frac{d}{x})e^{-a(|x|+|y|+|z|)}a^{5/2}(x+iy)}dxdydz$

$z\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-a(|x|+|y|+|z|}(x+iy))$, according to wolframalpha this gives an $a'$ in the derivative… how can this be?

Comment: what about $x>0, y>0, z>0$?

Comment: @VVV, Each variable $x$, $y$, $z$ takes positive and negative values. So if you enumerate all the joint possibilities, you should get $2^3 = 8$ possibilities. Like (positive, positive, positive), (positive, positive, negative), ..., (negative, negative, positive), (negative, negative, negative).  Now, you missed out the possibility $x < 0, y >0, z > 0$.

Comment: There should be 8 cases: three variables and depending on whether they are positive or not. However, The integral are symmetric with respect to $x$ and $y$, i.e. the integral for $x>0, y<0$ is the same as the integral for $x<0, y>0$. This help us to reduces to the following cases: (i) $x>0, y>0, z>0$ (ii) $x>0, y>0, z>0$ (iii) $x<0, y<0, z>0$ (iv) $x<0, y<0, z<0$ (v) $x>0, y<0, z>0$ (vi) $x>0, y<0, z<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do away with case analysis completely. Notice that the integral is completely symmetric w.r.t. the eight orthants; i.e., if you flip the sign of any variable, the integrand remains unchanged. So, immediately you can rewrite the integral as
$$
\iiint_{\mathbb R^3} a^5 e^{-2a(|x|+|y|+|z|)}(x^{2}+y^{2}) \ dx \ dy \ dz 
= 8 \iiint_{D} a^5 e^{-2a(|x|+|y|+|z|)}(x^{2}+y^{2}) \ dx \ dy \ dz 
$$
where $D$ is the positive orthant $\{ (x,y,z) \mid x, y, z \geqslant 0 \}$. You can further simplify this to:
$$
8 \iiint_D  a^5 e^{-2a(x+y+z)}(x^2+y^2) \ dx \ dy \ dz. 
$$

**Further manipulations:** In what follows, I manipulate the integral systematically to evaluate it. Before reading on, make sure you have attempted the integral and then compare our methods.

Split the integral into the sum 
$$
8 \iiint_D a^5 e^{-2a(x+y+z)} x^2 \ dx \ dy \ dz + 
8 \iiint_D a^5 e^{-2a(x+y+z)} y^2 \ dx \ dy \ dz  .
$$
The above two integrals are equal (by interchanging the variables $x \leftrightarrow y$). So the integral can be written simply as
$$
16 \iiint_D a^5 e^{-2a(x+y+z)} x^2 \ dx \ dy \ dz = 16a^5 \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty (e^{-2ax} x^5) \cdot e^{-2ay} \cdot e^{-2az} \ dx \  dy \ dz.
$$
Now we can split the integral as a product of three integrals:
$$
16a^5 \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-2ay} \ dy \right) \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-2az} \ dz \right) \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-2ax} x^2 \ dx \right).
$$
The first two integrals are easy and standard: they evaluate to $\frac{1}{2a}$. Plugging in this value, we can simplify the above expression to
$$
16a^5 \cdot \frac{1}{2a} \cdot \frac{1}{2a} \cdot \int_0^\infty e^{-2ax} x^2 \ dx 
= 4a^3 \int_0^\infty e^{-2ax} x^2 \ dx .
$$
Make the substitution $u = 2a x$ (*typo corrected*) to get
$$
4a^3 \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \frac{u^2}{4a^2} \ \frac{1}{2a} du = \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \cdot \frac{u^2}{2} du.
$$ 
Integrating the above by parts, we get
$$
-\left. e^{-u} \left( \frac{u^2}{2} + u + 1 \right) \right|_{u=0}^{u=\infty} = 1.
$$

Comment: Thank you, I get $\frac{1}{a^{5}}$ as a result.

Comment: @VVV Are you sure? The correct answer is be a number independent of $a$.

Comment: @VVV Full solution with lots and lots of manipulation; enjoy! =)